# How to keep a method's `this` from reffering to the object that called it

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this isn't clear, but I have to objects `A` and `B`. A creates an instance of B. B has a method `bar` that invokes a callback function. The function passed to B is one of A's methods `foo`, but foo's this refers to B not A. How do I fix this.

```
function A(){
  this.test=(new B(this.foo));
  this.test.bar();
}
A.prototype.foo=function(){
  console.log(this instanceof A);//needs to return true
}

function B(fn){
  this.fn=fn;
}
B.prototype.bar=function(){
  this.fn();
}
var a=new A();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very unusual data structure here. Anyway, you can set the context and args for future invocations of a *function* using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
function A(){
    this.test=(new B(this.foo.bind(this)));
    this.test.bar();
}
```

Please be aware that *binding* creates a new instance of the function, so `===` will now fail;

```
function foo() {}
var bar = foo.bind(null),
    baz = foo.bind(null);
foo === bar; // false
bar === baz; // false
baz === foo; // false
```

Comment: The structure is a little strange. B is actually a sprite object that handles playing through an image sprite. The callback is for when the sprite has finished one loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply passing the function of `A`'s `foo` to `B` constructor, you must still bind `A`'s `this` to `foo` before to ensure it is called properly.

```
function A() {
    this.test = new B(this.foo.bind(this));
    this.test.bar();
}
```